# Darwin libraries validation not yet implemented

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rvm

Trying to setup Rails environment on OS X. When I run `rvm reinstall all --force`, I get an error message:

```
"Darwin libraries validation not yet implemented"
```

Not one mention of that error message in Google. I'm curious what it means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message is because Linux bianry ruby is verified with `ldd`, the same check for OSX can be implemented using `otool -L` here: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/blob/master/scripts/external#L307

You can find more information about binary rubies reading:

```
rvm help install
rvm help mount
```